# Get the Storage location of Powerpoint add-ins Mac

Tags: vba, macos, cocoa, powerpoint, office-addins

I have to add the powerpoint Add-in to Powerpoint Mac from my cocoa application.I already adding the .ppam file from my cocoa application through below code

```
 NSString *pluginPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Kahani2016" ofType:@"ppam"];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:pluginPath];
```

Its working with most of powerpoint. 
We can view the added powerpoint add-in from powerpoint

[image]

But some systems Its showing below error message
[image]

I am trying to fix this issue. I tried to fix this issue by adding digital signature with .ppam file . but its not help to solve the issue.
I just confused because I tried to recreate this issue in another machine with same OSX and Powerpoint version but its working fine in another machine. 
My configurations
Powerpoint 15.29.1 Mac

So if I get the location of the powerpoint-Addin , then I can try to copy my add-ins to the location and fix the issue.

Comment: I see you have two PowerPoint:mac add-ins. Is the first targeted for 2011 and the second for 2016? What does your pluginPath resolve to for both Mac configurations? On the system that shows the error, can you manually load the Kahani.ppam file via the PowerPoint:mac Tools/[PowerPoint ]Add-Ins... menu without the error? FYI, digital signatures added to PPAM files on Windows are ignored on a Mac.

Comment: @JamieG: First of all Please ignore the name of ppam file . I just write two ppam files. I cant able to open ppam file to powerpoint from app using the code and the same error will get once we double click on the ppam file from finder. 
Yes, I can able to add the ppam file manually from powerpoint (Tools->Powerpoint addins-> add) and its working like charm.

Comment: @JamieG : Finding add-in path and coping the add-in to the path and solving the issue is just my thought , I don't know is that really works. some what I have to solve this issue.

Comment: Start a new file, add a few lines of code then attempt to save it as an Add-in (PPAM). PowerPoint normally opens the save-as dialog box on whatever folder it considers the default for add-ins.  However, from the error message you're getting, it seems that PowerPoint is finding the file but rejecting it for some other reason/s that the error message lists.